# How do I keep my throat cleared while singing?

Tags: voice

I love to sing, but for the past couple days I've had a problem where I am in constant need of throat clearing while singing. I'd never had this problem before. I know noisily clearing it is bad for you, and I found safer methods online, but it appears to be the only effective way to remove it. How can I fix this?

Comment: If I have a bit of a cold I have a menthol cough sweet before practice, works a treat.

Answer (score 6):

This is a result of excess mucus in your throat.  [Fly Paper](http://flypaper.soundfly.com/tips/musical-tips/keep-singing-voice-healthy/) recommends granny smith apples to get rid of it.  The article also has other useful tips for keeping your singing voice healthy.

> **An Apple a Day Keeps the Mucus Away**. Wait…that’s not the saying, is it? An old opera trick is to keep a baggie of cubed granny smith apples backstage. The acid effectively “burns” off excess mucus, without damaging the vocal chords, or causing acid reflux—which eating too close to bedtime and boozing without a care will do.

Answer (score 3):

These may help, but you'll learn over time what works for you:

- Drink lots of water (caffinated, milky or alcoholic drinks can cause
  this kind of effect)
- Swallow, don't cough.
- Try a sharp out-breath with your throat as open as possible, don't cough, but force a lot of air through your throat.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use warm water and Tom Tom. I don't know if other countries have Tom Tom but if you know it, then put two or three inside the warm water, allow it to melt and drink. Or get an okra and chew till it smooth and swallow it. it a bit hard but you won't regret it. Do this for a week and you will sing better. Avoid frying foods and cold water/food. Drink enough water.

Comment: Hmmmm, would you mind to to get more in detail about 'Tom Tom'?